# How can I send an analog signal through an ESP32 at 2000 hz and receive it in python at the same frequency through a serial port?

Tags: python, arduino, esp32

lately i've been trying to capture an ECG signal through an ESP32 board in real time at 2 kHz.
However, when i execute the python code, there are times where the frequency variation i'ts up or under 50% of the intended. Also there are instances where the first element acquired in the python script its not an analog value (for Example '125'), but more like '128r/110'.

My code for the ESP32 it's the following:

```
const int sampleRate = 2000; // Desired Sample Rate
const int periodUs = 1000000 / sampleRate; // micro-second delay or period


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(74880); // Serial comunication a
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long startTime = micros(); // Loop Start
  // Sendt the analog value as a byte
  Serial.println(analogRead(analogPin)); // Sends the 8 most significative bits
  // period delay
  unsigned long elapsedTime = micros() - startTime;
  while (elapsedTime < periodUs) {
    elapsedTime = micros() - startTime;
  }
}
```

As for my Python Script:

```
import serial

ser= serial.Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=115200)


t_end = time.time() + 10
t0 = time.time()
while (time.time() < t_end):
    data.append(ser.readline().decode().strip())  # read the serial data and convert it from bytes to string
t1 = time.time()
#wait until all the data is recorded from the serial port
print(data)
#
freq = round(len(data)/(t1-t0))
print(freq)

n_data = [int(x) for x in data]
```

So i'm trying to run a stable 2kHz code.

Comment: I'm not good in ESP and python but you have different baudrate.

Comment: ahh yes, i was trying differnt baud rates, both syncronous and asyncronous. It improves, but the variation stills high.

Answer (score 0):

**Timing**

One thing you could try is to wait on startime + (n x periodUs), this way it will try to correct timing differences (over multiple samples).  In your code you reset startTime each time so there is no attempt to correct for early or late samples.

But i don't know if it will help since you mentioned you get +/- 50% samplerate which is a LOT, not even sure how you can get +50% ...

Also, i would try with a baudrate around 56000, i don't think it will help much if you increase it.

```
void loop() {
    unsigned long startTime = micros(); // Loop Start

    while (true) {
        // Send the analog value as a byte
        Serial.println(analogRead(analogPin));

        // period
        startTime += periodUs;
        while (micros() < startTime) { }
    }
}
```

**Protocol (edit:added)**

If your samples are only single bytes, you could write it as a byte stream, it won't be less reliable then newline terminated strings and the data rate would be lower.

arduino: `Serial.write( (byte)(analogRead(analogPin) >> 4) );  // most signifacant 8 bits`

python: `data.append(ser.read())`

Comment: sorry for the delay,but, just to let you know that the code helped me to improve the serial reading. Thank you so much.